# Allowing user to favorite a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on allowing a user to favorite a post.

I've created a model called favorite.

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

it stores the user_id and post_id.

I've also created a FavoritesController

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    current_user.favorite(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    current_user.unfavorite(@post)
  end

end
```

the form I have on my Posts#index is:

```
<%= form_for current_user.favorites.build do |favorite| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, f.id %>
  <%= favorite.button do %>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

my user model looks like this:

```
# Favorites a post.
def favorite(post)
  favorite.create(post_id: post)
end

# Unfavorites a post.
def unfavorite(post)
  favorite.find_by(post_id: post).destroy
end
```

when I try to click on favorite I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"HjiANQUqTQVEqy0yzfLFMlnC8RsTiY5kVlvIUnD5OSIaSYSi4ELSuC95vRMIBA/6W+KvzCWMMXQ==",
"post_id"=>"7",
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What line is the error on? One problem is that in your `favorite` method you are passing in a post, but then calling create with a post_id.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom so I tried changing the favorite method from favorite to favorites and now it reloads but nothing happens. It says line: 43 which is my def favorite(post)

Comment: You can't use `favorites` as that is already defined as part of "use has many favorites".

Comment: aha. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Can you post your complete error log please

Comment: @Pavan that is the entire error log

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a 'voting/favoriting' system working, I suggest using a gem like https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable or something of the like.